# (Possible incorrect location) Duplicate question incorrect duplicate

Tags: support

So the other day I asked [Term for situation where alternative choice is not really one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199649/term-for-situation-where-alternative-choice-is-not-really-one)

and it was marked as a duplicate of another, however the duplicate doesn't correctly answer the question. A better duplicate would have been
[Expression for a choice which isn't really one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/expression-for-a-choice-which-isnt-really-one)
as listed in a comment.

--
I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask/submit this

Comment: You are correct, that question was not a duplicate. Maybe a mod can swap out the better choice for the original.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct place to ask. I have replaced the duplicate with the one you've requested.

Thanks for raising the issue.